# applying a function to a numpy array not working as I expected

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, lambda

```
>>> ndarr = np.array([0, 1, 2])
>>> (lambda x: x + 1) (ndarr)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

I see that it replaces every element with the function applied to it.

but when I do this to a two dimensional array:

```
>>> ndarr = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
>>> (lambda x: x[0]) (ndarr)
array([0, 1, 2])
```

I thought this would take the two elements of the array which are [0, 1, 2] and [3, 4, 5], apply the lambda to them resulting in 0 and 3, and the result would be [0, 3]. but this applies the function to the whole array instead. why? and wat do I do to get [0, 3]?

Comment: you're probably looking for this - ndarr[:,0] (from each row, select 1st element)

Comment: You are just doing `ndarr[0]`, which selects the first row.   The lambda function layer does not change the behavior.  The whole `ndarr` array is passed as `x`.  There's no iteration implied by the function call.  Similarly in the first case, the `lambda` doesn't iterate.  You are just doing `ndarr+1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying `+ 1` on a `numpy` array will cause all elements to be incremented by one, as you have noticed.
However, this does not imply that every operation you perform using a `numpy` array will be a "mapping". In the second example, there is simply a nested list, and you select the first element of the outer list. The exact same would happen if you just used regular Python:

```py
>>> nlist = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> (lambda x: x[0]) (nlist)
[0, 1, 2]
```

You are looking for a mapping if you want to apply an operation on each of the nested arrays. However, this problem can be solved with a slice most easily:

```py
>>> ndarr = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
>>> ndarr[:,0]
array([0, 3])
```